# DataFormatString: the field must be a number

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, culture

I have this model:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal SpotPrice { get; set; }
```

In my details view it displays prices as "25,00". When I try to edit the price, the field is pre-filled with the database entry "25,00". When I hit save immediately I get this error: `"The field SpotPrice must be a number."`

With the suggestions given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985545/asp-net-mvc4-tutorial-scaffolding-validation-and-display-use-several-different) I have set my global culture in Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
<globalization culture="nl-NL"/>
</system.web>
```

I have also tried many different DataFormatStrings, but none of them allow me to get rid of that error message.

I use SQL Server to store the prices.

Edit: updated the question:
What can I do to make this price field validate properly?

Edit: Here's my Edit method, which I use to save the new price:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CampingSpotId,SpotName,FieldName,Surface,Wifi,Water,Sewer,Reserved,Booked,SpotPrice,Type")] CampingSpot campingSpot)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _campingspotrepository.SetModified(campingSpot);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(campingSpot);
}
```

SetModified method does this:

```
public void SetModified(CampingSpot campingSpot)
{
    db.Entry(campingSpot).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you hit save?

Comment: I get this error `"The field price must be a number"` http://piclair.com/data/2c6in.jpg

Comment: In other words, it won't save at all

Comment: I mean, what is the code that is doing the save operation?

Comment: @Downvoter, please specifiy why you downvote this question. I have done research to similiar questions, but couldn't come up with a solution based on those questions.

Comment: Go into SSMS and try manually adding a row as `25,00`. Most likely your database is looking for `25.00`, so when the SQL string is passed with the comma, it's blowing up.

Comment: @krillgar, I am perfectly able to manually add a row as `25,00`.

Comment: @krillgar Is it even getting that far?  It looks like MVC is rejecting the model as invalid before it even gets to that point.  Is ModelState.IsValid true or false in this method?

Comment: Does this work if you remove the DataFormatString?  Does it work if you just use "{0:c}" instead?  I can't figure out what that format string is supposed to do.

Comment: @Moby Disk, I can as well leave it out. Seems like the same behavour applies when I don't use the DataFormatString at all. It is the HTML validation that fails here.

Comment: @Moby Disk, changed it to `{0:c}`, the error is still the same.

Comment: First of all, that message comes from the framework, not the SQL, so you can leave that part out of the equation. Secondly, the `{0:c}` format (currency), normally adds a special character, usually `$`. Does the control let you type a $ before the number? What happens if you use `0:F` instead? 
More about the formatting: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You must write `[DataType(DataType.Currency)]` in Model

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal SpotPrice { get;set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with currency and date formats. If noone has a proper solution, a workaround is to make SpotPrice a string and validate it server-side:

```
 public string SpotPriceStr { get; set; }
```

Within the controller, convert to decimal and if that fails, add an error to ModelState.